# How to create a 'shallow' tar archive without the actual file data?

Tags: bash, indexing, tar, ls

Is there a way to create a tar archive that will only contain file names but omit the actual file data?

The intent is to create a hierarchical 'mirror' of a drive that will only contain the directory structure and file names (preferably with sizes) but omit the actual file data.

The purpose is to generate an inventory of what is on a disk, i.e. something that would be better and faster than the output of `ls -R -S -l /` but possibly in a less verbose format.

I am aware that the question is about [mis-]using `tar` for something that it is not meant to be used for, but would like to investigate all options and push the limits of what is possible.

One possible option I'm experimenting with is creating a RAM `tmpfs` filesystem (in order to avoid writing to disk unnecessarily and increase the speed) and then use `lndir` (from the `xutils-dev` package) to mirror the entire subtree using symlinks `lndir /media/usb1 /ramtmpfs` and then do `tar usb1-filelist.tar /ramtmpfs`. One limitation I'm running into with this approach is RAM size which is easily exceeded with large subtrees even if just creating symlinks. Is there a better/saner way, possibly something that `tar` can do on its own?

Comment: I would do this with Python's `tarfile` module.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: does the phython `tarfile` module have an option to skip the file 'body' when archiving? i.e. make a 'shallow' archive?

Comment: @ccpizza, you can provide any body you want, including an empty one; it doesn't have to link to a real on-the-file-system file, certainly not one with the same name as the entry in the archive being generated.

Comment: nice! thanks; will have a look at it; because the `lndir` approach is too messy

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: confirming `tarfile` did the job; thanks!  wanted to have the real file size displayed, so experimented with gzip and in-memory `io.BytesIO()` files with content like `b'\x00' * size` — generates slightly bigger files than with zero-length files but with correct sizes!

Comment: We hope you'll post your code as an answer.

Comment: @shellter: added the answer using `ZipFile`; the version with `TarFile+TarInfo` is almost identical but with some extra quirks that I still didn't figure out how to fix.

Comment: @ccpizza : Good show!

Comment: What you are going to achieve, looks so unusual, that it's perhaps a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Maybe it would help if you explained what you are using this shallow tar file for?

Comment: @user1934428: you are absolutely right; this was more of an exploration of options and an exercise in futility; I've updated my answer to mention that `tree` is in fact a more suitable, faster and more efficient solution for the original use case I had.

Comment: I don't know the exact output format for `tree`, but if you need later to parse this representation, it could give you headaches depending on the characters in the filenames. I would more likely give `find ... -print0` a chance.

Comment: `tree` is versatile and can generate plain text, HTML, JSON, XML and the recursive traversal speed is subjectively faster than `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

Following the hint from @CharlesDuffy here is the python compression with both `tarfile` (for .tar.gz) and `zipfile` (for .zip). It takes the folder to 'archive' as 1st arg and the name of the resulting TAR archive.

Filling with zeros is only needed in order to display the correct original file size. Omitting it will speed up the operation significantly since compressing zeros is extra overhead, especially when files are huge.

##### Create TAR file with fake zero-filled files

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import pathlib
import sys
import tarfile


def create_tar(folder: str, archive: str):
    # compresslevel=1 - fastest, bigger file
    # compresslevel=9 - slowest, smallest file
    with tarfile.open(archive, mode="w:gz", compresslevel=1) as tar:
        for path in pathlib.Path(folder).glob('**/*'):
            if path.is_file():
                size: int = path.stat().st_size
                if path.name.startswith(('.DS_Store', '._')):
                    print(f'Skipping {path.absolute()}')
                    continue

                print(f'adding {path.absolute()}...', end='')

                tar_info: tarfile.TarInfo = tarfile.TarInfo(name=str(path))
                tar_info.size = size
                memfile = io.BytesIO()
                memfile.write(b'\x00' * size)
                memfile.seek(0)
                tar.addfile(tarinfo=tar_info, fileobj=memfile)

                print('ok')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder: str = sys.argv[1]
    archive_name: str = sys.argv[2]

    create_tar(folder, archive_name)
```

#### Create ZIP file with fake zero-filled files

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import zipfile
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
from zipfile import ZipInfo


def create_zip(folder: str, archive_name: str):
    with ZipFile(file=archive_name, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipper:
        for path in Path(folder).glob('**/*'):
            if path.is_file():
                size: int = path.stat().st_size
                if path.name.startswith(('.DS_Store', '._')):
                    print(f'Skipping {path.absolute()}')
                    continue

                print(f'adding {path.absolute()}...', end='')

                modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(path.stat().st_mtime)
                dt = (modified.year, modified.month, modified.day, modified.hour, modified.minute, modified.second)
                zip_info: zipfile.ZipInfo = ZipInfo(filename=str(path), date_time=dt)
                zip_info.file_size = size  # if you set data=b'' + zipfile.ZIP_STORED then this *must* be zero or unset

                # create 0-length files
                # zipper.writestr(zip_info, data=b'', compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_STORED)

                # create dummy files filled with zero that compress well (for original file size display)
                zipper.writestr(zip_info, data=b'\x00' * size, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                print('ok')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    folder: str = sys.argv[1]
    archive_name: str = sys.argv[2]

    archive: str = create_zip(folder, archive_name)
```

##### Alternatives

Given that the original purpose of the tar was to generate an 'inventory' of a specific subtree for archival purposes that won't include the actual data, `tar` is **not** the best tool for this.

A more suitable tool for this could be gnu [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) or [`tree`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree); for example to create a JSON file with a directory listing of `/media/usb0` that will include modification dates and file sizes:

```bash
tree -J --dirsfirst --charset utf-8 --ignore-case \
    --timefmt '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M' -s -D \
    -o usb0-index.json /media/usb0
```

Alternative approach with `find` to create a tsv file (implies GNU `find`, *not* bsd/macos `find` (use `gfind` on mac after installing with `brew install findutils`):

```bash
find . -not -path "*/.Spotlight-V100/*" \
  -not -path "*/.DS_Store*/*" \
  -not -path "*/.Trash/*" \
  -printf "%P\t%s\t%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\n" > files.tsv
```

Now `files.tsv` can be imported into e.g. an sqlite database:

```bash
sqlite3 files.db ".mode tabs" ".import files.tsv mytable"
```